# session not working the way it should

Tags: php

I am using sessions to keep track of users.
on another page it sets the username and password variable when the user logs in and then redirects to this page.

for security reasons when the user comes here I want to check that the user is logged in. If the user isn't logged in then it will redirect the user to the index.php page

```
<?php 

  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['sessionid'])) {
if (isset ($_SESSION['username' and 'password'])){
}
else
{
    header("Location:Index.php");
}
  }
?>
```

the problem is that if I just load the page by typing in the relevant URL I am not redirected to the index page

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you seriously storing the password in the session along with the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend against storing that information in the session.  That being said, you have an error in your syntax:

```
if (isset ($_SESSION['username']) && isset ($_SESSION['password'])) {...}
```

But, if I can add further, I would recommend (at very minimum) creating either a class or function to do this for you, as you'll be using it more than just once I assume.

Create yourself a function, for example:

```
function is_logged_in () {
  if ((isset ($_SESSION['username'])) && (isset ($_SESSION['password']))) {
    /* this is an awful way of checking if a user is logged in! */
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then, when you need to check if a user is logged in, just reference that function:

```
if (is_logged_in ()) {
  /* show members only stuff */
} else {
  echo 'Please login';
}
```

Then, as you learn more and proceed with your application you can adjust one function instead of having to go back and update the login check everywhere in your code.

BUT: Please, please, please read up on user security, or even better use one of many pre-made packages.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this :) this is part of my assignment for designing a CMS system that has to be handed in shortly so I don't have time to make the site 100% secure but it is likely that I will be doing a similar thing for my Final year project next academic year so I will keep this in mind thanks :)

I intend to put this entire script in an include at some point :)

first I want to actually get the backend i.e the part of the CMS I have to do for my assignment before touching it up though :)

Comment: Cool.  Good luck with your project.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong way of checking in if statement use this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])  && isset($_SESSION[ 'password']))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `isset ($_SESSION['username' and 'password'])` you don’t check whether the two variable `$_SESSION['username']` and `$_SESSION['password']` exist but whether the `$_SESSION` variable with key `'username' and 'password'` (which evaluates to `true`) exists, so basically `isset($_SESSION[true])`.

You actually need to list both variables:

```
isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a sintax error in your `if` condition, you need to declare your session values separatly so change to this

```
if((isset($_SESSION['username'])) && (isset($_SESSION['password']))) {
```